# Spring Statemachine context variables not updating in action

Tags: spring-statemachine

I am having some problems with Spring statemachine + Spring boot application.

I am using Redis for persistence, as in [Event service](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-examples-eventservice) demo. I have one action which is executed when state machine enters state 'VALIDATION'. In it, I modify extended state variables. Code example below is simplified, but tested:

This is main, calling method:

```
 public void feedMachine(String event, int orderItem) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("DEBUG FEEDMACHINE STARTED");
    StateMachine<String, String> machine = persister.restore(stateMachine, orderItem);
    machine.sendEvent(event);
    System.out.println("DEBUG FEEDMACHINE... machine = " + machine.getUuid());
    System.out.println("DEBUG FEEDMACHINE... variables = " + machine.getExtendedState().getVariables());
    if (machine.getExtendedState().getVariables().containsKey("guard")
            && !machine.getExtendedState().get("guard", Boolean.class)) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG FEEDMACHINE... guard = " + machine.getExtendedState().get("guard", Boolean.class));
        throw new GuardedEventException();
    }
    persister.persist(machine, orderItem);
    System.out.println("DEBUG FEEDMACHINE ENDED");
}
```

This is action:

```
@Bean
public Action<String, String> CustomerOrderValidatedEntryAction() {
    return new Action<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext context) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG ACTION STARTED");
            System.out.println("DEBUG ACTION... machine = " + context.getStateMachine().getUuid());

            int orderItem = context.getStateMachine().getExtendedState().get(ORDER_ITEM, Integer.class);
            context.getExtendedState().getVariables().put("guard", false);
            System.out.println("DEBUG ACTION... variables = " + context.getExtendedState().getVariables());
                persister.persist(context.getStateMachine(), key);
                System.out.println("DEBUG ACTION ENDED");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

When I leave action, in feedMachine extendedState.getVariables does not contain guard and errors variable.

This is output:

```
DEBUG FEEDMACHINE STARTED
2016-08-16 11:46:17.101  INFO 26483 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@a85eba8
2016-08-16 11:46:17.102  INFO 26483 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped ...  /  / uuid=336abc3e-708e-46ad-892f-5835b50713c8 / id=null
2016-08-16 11:46:17.102  INFO 26483 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@a85eba8
2016-08-16 11:46:17.102  INFO 26483 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started ...  / ORDER_RECEIVED / uuid=336abc3e-708e-46ad-892f-5835b50713c8 / id=null
DEBUG ACTION STARTED
DEBUG ACTION... machine = 336abc3e-708e-46ad-892f-5835b50713c8
DEBUG ACTION... guard = false
DEBUG ACTION... variables = {orderItem=0, guard=false}
DEBUG ACTION ENDED
DEBUG FEEDMACHINE... machine = 336abc3e-708e-46ad-892f-5835b50713c8
DEBUG FEEDMACHINE... variables = {orderItem=0}
DEBUG FEEDMACHINE ENDED
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure if this is connected with Spring statemachine or with Spring beans or something else.
I apologize for primitive code (using println instead of log.debug etc.).

**EDIT:**

I finally found out where was the problem.
I was using in action `context.getExtendedState().getVariables().put("guard", valid);` instead of `context.getStateMachine().getExtendedState().getVariables().put("guard", valid);`. Now it works as expected. Problem was that those two variables lists were not same.

- `context.getExtendedState()`'s variables list would get updated with "guard"
- `context.getStateMachine().getExtendedState()`'s variables list would not get updated.

However, after creating minimal working example (only 3 states instead of 15+, no nested states), it was working correctly with `context.getExtendedState().getVariables().put("guard", valid);`.
I also checked several days ago whether `context.getExtendedState()` and `context.getStateMachine().getExtendedState()` are same, and I concluded that they were.

This seems to me as a bug.

Comment: Little difficult to say without seeing full example(to see machine config and version, etc). Could you isolate a test case or a sample I could run?

Comment: While I was simplifying my code (removing almost all states, all unnecessary variables etc.) so I could post it here, I realized that it works fine. After many hours of debugging, I realized what is the problem, but I'm not sure why. I edited main post.